# Google Cloud Datastore connection resets every 4 to 5 minutes

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am experimenting with Google Datastore. I have found that connection keeps resetting every 4 to 5 minutes. Is there anything I can do about it?

The first query after connection is reset generally takes between 800 to 1000ms. This is really not the experience I was looking forward to. And definitely not our users.

Here is the code I have. Every 4 to 5 minutes I see `** Resetting DB connection...` on console.

```
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.cloud.exceptions import ServiceUnavailable


class DbException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message, *errors):
        Exception.__init__(self, message)
        self.errors = errors


class DataStore(object):

    def __init__(self, entity_kind, json_credentials_path, project):
        self._entity_kind = entity_kind
        self._client = datastore.Client.from_service_account_json(
            json_credentials_path=json_credentials_path,
            project=project)

    def _key(self, urn):
        return self._client.key(self._entity_kind, urn)

    def find(self, urn):
        try:
            return self._client.get(self._key(urn))
        except ServiceUnavailable:
            print('** Resetting DB connection...')
            return self.find(urn)

    def insert(self, urn, data, **kwargs):
        try:
            if not self.find(urn) is None:
                raise DbException('Entity already exists.')

            if 'exclude_from_indexes' in kwargs:
                exi = kwargs['exclude_from_indexes']
                entity = datastore.Entity(key=self._key(urn),
                                          exclude_from_indexes=exi)
            else:
                entity = datastore.Entity(key=self._key(urn))

            entity.update(data)
            self._client.put(entity)
        except ServiceUnavailable:
            print('** Resetting DB connection...')
            self.insert(urn, entity)
```

Comment: Are you in App Engine standard or App Engine - Flexible Environment? If the latter, are you running with compat runtime enabled?

Comment: @DanMcGrath: This is my development MAC, if that helps. Eventually, this will be part of a Docker container hosted on Google Container Engine.

Comment: Can you try it in the Cloud Shell via the Cloud Console. I'd hazard a guess this is something happening on your network connection between your Mac and our network, rather than being code related.